# how to create dynamic database table using csv file in django or DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, dynamic-programming

I am going to create a database table using csv file without model in django. Steps are:
after sending csv file by post request, one database table will be created according to csv headers (name, university, score, total_score etc). And it will be populated using csv file data. Database table name should be derived from csv file name.
I searched but couldn't find good solution.
Any help is appreciated.
Below is my code to read csv file
class UploadProductApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    file = serializer.validated_data['file']
    decoded_file = file.read().decode()
    # upload_products_csv.delay(decoded_file, request.user.pk)
    io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
    reader = csv.reader(io_string)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a dynamic Django model: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

With this approach you could create models on the fly and by running this snippet

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('makemigrations')
call_command('migrate')
```

you could migrate the model to the database and use it for accessing and storing the csv data. After that you should create the model code with `inspectdb`:

```
python manage.py inspectdb TableName > output.py
```

Set the path to the where you want your model file to be generated. I'm not certain if this command would overwrite or append to the current file, so you can try to append to current file, if it doesn't work make a temp file and write the output to it and append it to your desired models.py file: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-append-content-of-one-text-file-to-another/

After the whole process you will have migrations generated, executed and the model in models.py for use on server restart.